# EnumDropDownListFor Conditionally hide items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to conditionally hide the elements in the `EnumDropDownListFor` based on if the user is logged in or not.

**Enum**

```
public enum SortType
{
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(NavigationItems), Name = "BestMatch")]
    Best_Match = 0,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(NavigationItems), Name = "Alphabetical")]
    Alphabetical,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(NavigationItems), Name = "PriceAsc")]
    PriceAsc,
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(NavigationItems), Name = "PriceDesc")]
    PriceDesc
}
```

The items I am looking to hide are `PriceAsc` & `PriceDesc`
I have tried looking into the `AutoGenerateFilter` and `AutoGenerateField` properties to no avail.

**View**

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.sortType, new { id = "orderResults" })
```

Comment: How about scrapping the EnumDropDownListFor and implement your own custom helper that checks user.identity.isauthenticated?

Comment: This is how I would have done this previously, I was hoping there was some nice MVC 5.1 way of doing this :)

Comment: You can find the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133014/exclude-remove-value-from-mvc-5-1-enumdropdownlistfor

Answer (score -2):

```
var sortTypesToExclude = new[] { SortType.PriceAsc, SortType.PriceDesc }.Cast<int>();
var sortTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SortType)).Cast<int>().Where(i => userLoggedIn || !sortTypesToExclude.Contains(i));
var sortTypesAsSelectList = sortTypes.Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Value = i.ToString(), Text = ((SortType)i).ToString() });
```